# Flutter - Image persistence on the phone where I develop the app

Tags: flutter

It is the first app I develop. I notice that I get a problem with image persistence on the phone where I develop the app. It looks like it doesn't really refresh the screen (When it opens a new screen, you can still see a faded version of the former screen, or some parts of it). It is a Samsung A21s.

Is this linked to the developing ? It doesn't seem to do the same thing on other apps that I use ? Or is it a problem with the phone ?
I bought it exclusively for the developing work.

Anyone has the same problem ?

Comment: Screen burns can cause that kind of effects on the polarizer screen

Comment: Is there anything that can be done ? What is it caused by ?